# Как изменить стиль оформления элементов WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

Чтобы было похоже на Windows 10.

Comment: Пробовали Mahapps Metro?

Comment: Установил Mahapps. На чёрном фоне белые элементы (текстовые поля итп). Смотрится ужасно. Устанавливалось как здесь http://mahapps.com/guides/quick-start.html

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать Theme.
Я пользуюсь готовой библиотекой от Telerik.

```
 <Button telerik:StyleManager.Theme="Vista">
```